# Hover Effect Below Position Absolute

Tags: javascript, css

There are three tags included in my problem.

1. A wrapper div that goes around my image and is positioned relatively.
2. An anchor tag that is positioned absolute with a width and height of 100%. This way a user can click anywhere on the image to go to it's url, or have the ability to right click and open in a new tab.
3. Finally there is the image tag.

My goal is to add an effect to the image when a user hovers over the image. As you can see with the `onmousover` alert attribute The only problem is when you hover of the image only the hover over the anchor tag is triggered. So I'm guessing I somehow need to propagate my onmouseover down to the image? I'm at a loss any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Oh and please avoid any frameworks (jquery, prototype), just js and css please. Thank you so much.

```
<div class="boardPostImage">
    <a href="image?id=${image.id}" class="boardPostImageAnchor"></a>
    <img alt="${boardPost.content}" src="${initParam.imageCropMedium}${image.id}.jpg" onmouseover="alert('hello')" />
</div>
```

Comment: Why not `<a><img/></a>` ? And you can put the action inside a function, `MouseOverImage()`. Now when you hover over the anchor, you can execute that function anytime.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but that would not work. As I said the anchor is position absolute. If I wrapped that around my image it too would then be position absolute and wreck the entire flow of the webpage. That's why the anchor has to stand alone.

Comment: did you try set z-index to make the img stay on top of the anchor?

Comment: @Shuping then he won't be able to click on the link...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on keeping the anchor separated from the image, then its ok.

JavaScript Solution:

```
function HoverOverImage()
{
    alert("Hello");
}

function HoverOverAnchor()
{
   //Do the stuff you want
   //Execute the other function
   HoverOverImage();
}

<a href="image?id=${image.id}" class="boardPostImageAnchor" onmouseover="HoverOverAnchor()"></a>
```

JQuery Solution:

```
$("img").mouseover(function(){
        alert("Hello");
});

$("a").mouseover(function(){
        $("img").mouseover();
});
```

Comment: Great idea. This is almost perfect. But I need to send the this variable of the img to the function b/c I will not know the image id. That is how I will add an effect to that image on mouse over. Any ideas?